# I am getting an invalid read of size one error from valgrind when I try to use fopen

Tags: c, io, valgrind, fopen

This is what I get from valgrind:

```
==1654036== Thread 102:
==1654036== Invalid read of size 1
==1654036==    at 0x491328C: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:225)
==1654036==    by 0x4905B0D: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:75)
==1654036==    by 0x4905B0D: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==1654036==    by 0x10A9EC: readFromDisk (in /home/john/OS4061/p3/group/p3/web_server)
==1654036==    by 0x10AC72: worker (in /home/john/OS4061/p3/group/p3/web_server)
==1654036==    by 0x4866608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==1654036==    by 0x49A2292: clone (clone.S:95)
==1654036==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==1654036== 
==1654036== 
==1654036== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==1654036==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==1654036==    at 0x491328C: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:225)
==1654036==    by 0x4905B0D: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:75)
==1654036==    by 0x4905B0D: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==1654036==    by 0x10A9EC: readFromDisk (in /home/john/OS4061/p3/group/p3/web_server)
==1654036==    by 0x10AC72: worker (in /home/john/OS4061/p3/group/p3/web_server)
==1654036==    by 0x4866608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==1654036==    by 0x49A2292: clone (clone.S:95)
```

And here is the function

```
int readFromDisk(char *mybuf, char *request) {
    int num_bytes = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(request, O_RDONLY);
        if(file == NULL){
                return 0;
        }
        
    while(fread(mybuf,1, 1, file)!=EOF){
        num_bytes++;
    }
    return num_bytes;
}
```

I have tried printing request and it is a valid file path.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `O_RDONLY`? A string to specify open mode should go there. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Do turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: O_RDONLY is a parameter for open(), not fopen().  You want something like fopen(request, "r")

Comment: Review: Why use `EOF` in `fread(mybuf,1, 1, file)!=EOF`?

Comment: @John Use `-g` then run valgrind. This will give you exact line number.  Line number is missing in the log.  Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130246/valgrind-does-not-show-line-numbers

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out the problem with `O_RDONLY` being a valid value for `open` (not `fopen`), also

```
while(fread(mybuf,1, 1, file)!=EOF){
```

is not what you want.

The return value of [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/):

> The total number of elements successfully read is returned. If this
> number differs from the count parameter, either a reading error
> occurred or the end-of-file was reached while reading. In both cases,
> the proper indicator is set, which can be checked with ferror and
> feof, respectively. If either size or count is zero, the function
> returns zero and both the stream state and the content pointed by ptr
> remain unchanged. size_t is an unsigned integral type.

Switch to:

```
while(fread(mybuf,1, 1, file)==1){
```

And always prefer `size_t` when returning the size of a file

```
size_t readFromDisk(char *mybuf, char *request) {
    size_t num_bytes = 0;
    ...
```

EDIT 1:

*Now I'm getting an invalid read for fread, any ideas there?*

Better ask the system, add this outside the `while` loop:

```
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        perror("fread");
        return 0;
    }
```

and you may receive a hint, if you don't receive any hint you can try with [explain_fread](https://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_fread):

> The explain_fread function is used to obtain an explanation of an
> error returned by the fread(3) system call. The least the message will
> contain is the value of strerror(errno), but usually it will do much
> better, and indicate the underlying cause in more detail.

EDIT 2:

I also see (from the output of valgrind) that you are developing or using a web server, it is very likely that the error is not in `fread` but in the buffer that stores the content, surely valgrind is so vague and imprecise in the output due to (as pointed out by @KrishnaKanthYenumulayou in comments) the omission of the `-g` flag in the compilation.

Comment: From man page : "If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero)".

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula yes, and that's what is quoted: _..., the function returns zero and both the stream state and the content pointed by ptr remain unchanged_

Comment: Now I'm getting an invalid read for fread, any ideas there?

Comment: ==1655449== Invalid read of size 4 
==1655449== at 0x4906005: fread (iofread.c:37)

Comment: @DavidRanieri where in my function would I put the perror. I tried adding it before and  after the while loop and it never prints?

Comment: Can you isolate the error in a short compilable snippet and edit your question?  it will be easier for us to give you some help.

Comment: The program is too large to post. But I can edit to show you how I used perror.

Comment: There is no need to show the full code, just extract how you declare the buffer receiving the contents of the file and how you call the function, _Invalid read of size 4_ usually indicates an out of bound or misaligned access.

Answer (score 1):

```
==1654036==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

You are passing a NULL pointer to `fopen`. As per the comments and other answer, this is from O_RDONLY

```
/usr/include/sys/fcntl.h:#define    O_RDONLY    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
FILE *file = fopen(request, O_RDONLY);
```

to

```
FILE *file = fopen(request, "r");
```

That way, `fopen()` can succeed (if everything else is correct).

Comment: That got me a step further, now I have trouble with fread:

Comment: ==1655449== Thread 102:
==1655449== Invalid read of size 4
==1655449==    at 0x4906005: fread (iofread.c:37)